# Enable "Live Object Warning" in DXGI

Tags: direct3d, direct3d11, dxgi

In Direct3D 11, I can enable "live object warnings" like

```
D3D11: WARNING: Live Texture2D: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x02A16AAC, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #2097235: LIVE_TEXTURE2D ]
```

in my debug builds to detect objects that have not been released.

Can I do the same for DXGI? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IDXGIDebug ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh780351(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh780351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

IDXGIDebug offers a method called ReportLiveObjects.

Comment: Thank you. I will upgrade to Win8 SDK and give it a try.